# Lagrange Multipliers, two constraints.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Question: . Use Lagrange multipliers to ﬁnd the constrained critical points of f subject to the given constraints.

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kQEHR.png) is the equation and the [here is my solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3PSK9.jpg). I am stuck now and I don't know how to proceed. I got a couple of restrictions but that's about it.

Answer (score 1):

First of all: *Nobody cares about the values of $\lambda$ and $\mu$*.  So get rid of them by first substituting $\lambda$ from (1) in (2) and (3).  Subtract those two new equations to get $2\mu(-2y+3z)=0$.  Convince yourself that $\mu=0$ yields to no solution.  Hence $2y=3z$. Our first task is finished: no more $\lambda$, no more $\mu$.  From here we easily arrive in $x=\pm\sqrt{13}/7$, $y=\mp18\sqrt{13}/91$ and $z=\mp12\sqrt{13}/91$.

That gives a minimum and a maximum as expected, since the first constraint is a plane and the second the unit sphere and we're searching for those points with extremal first coordinate.

Comment: But 2y - x cannot equal 0 because if they do, then the equation (1) = (2) will give you 1 = 0 and thats not possible

Comment: You're right, I'll correct my answer.